# How to persist the gestures of the GestureOverLayView?

Tags: android, gesture

Suppose I am writing a word **"abc"** in my GestureOverlayView and while doing so I need to save all those alphabets in the screen until I press a **clear** button.Can anyone tell me a good way to do this.. 
I will write "a" which is taken as a gesture (not as stroke) i.e One thing I though of was like use a **ImageView** or **SurfaceView** on bottom of a GestureOverLayView.and Suppose when I draw "a" on GestureOverLayView then in the "onGesturePerformed" event it will take the Gesture and then get the strokes and then convert them into paths and then draw the paths onto the underlying ImageView or SurfaceView.Can anyone suggest me the code or guide me.I tried various combinations of them but couldn't solve it..

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called GestureBuilder in the samples directory of the SDK. This app shows how to persist gestures drawn by the user.

Comment: No it always goes empty whenever I start drawing a new gesture again

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but you can "cheat" by increasing the fadeOffset to some ridiculously high number. This can be done either in the xml

```
android:fadeOffset = "some very large number"
```

whatever, or programatically,

```
yourgestureoverlayView.SetFadeOffset(some very large number in milliseconds)
```

Comment: Please use code mark up in your answer for greater readability.