# Multiple color/stroke gesture and persist drawing in same GestureOverlayView

Tags: java, android, colors, android-canvas, gesture

I have seen many examples of drawing using gesture. My requirement is that, I want to draw **multiple colored and multiple stroked gesture** in same `GestureOverlayView`. To be more clear, please have a look at below image.

[image]

If user select different colors and different strokes, drawing should be of respective color/stroke. Now, its drawing different colored and different stroke gestures but **if I select different color or different stroke, previously drawn gesture also takes new color or new stroke**.

One similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383026/how-to-persist-the-gestures-of-the-gestureoverlayview/9384343#9384343) but has same issue.

Kindly suggest.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
       android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/white"
       android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="false"
       android:fadeEnabled="false"
       android:fadeOffset="122000"
       android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
       android:gestureStrokeWidth="6"
       android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

   </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

In java code, changing color code

```
mGestureOverlayView.setGestureColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Thanks.

**Edit :** Thought to implement same with `Canvas` and got code from [here](https://github.com/dhaval0122/Sample-Canvas-Android). Its drawing multiple lines but again problem is when I change color/stroke, recently drawn lines also taking new color/stroke. 
Please suggest whats going wrong here.

**Edit (Answer) :** Finally got solution. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806208/regarding-android-paint-drawing-color) link.

Comment: got answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806208/regarding-android-paint-drawing-color

Comment: If you found an answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not a comment. You can accept and get upvoted for your own answers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid this wouldn't be possible without rolling your own version of `GestureOverlayView` with considerable modification. Here's a run through of what you'd need to change.

Consider **what would be needed for this to work**:

1. You would need an iterable (or, in fact, `List` of some kind) of the past color settings- or in Android a stack of the past `Paint`s.
2. The `Gesture`s would need to be stored in a separable way. Inside `GestureOverlayView`, these are stored using Android's `Path`, so these would need to be seperable- given path's api, the only way to do this would be as different path instances that could be overlaid seperately.
3. Finally, there would have to be an *ordering* on the paths, so that the association between colours and paths could be made.

The above would, in very rough terms, enable you to iterate through to the latest path and colour and use the instance of `View`'s `draw(Canvas canvas)` method to `thisViewsCanvas.drawPath(mLatestAddedPaths.next(), mLatestPaintColor.next())` foreach path and paint.

*Finally, a little optimization would be to create each available paint colour when the view is created, and to hash it against its color, to save on paint creation. Your mLatestPaintColor list would then contain the hashes for the paints.

To see what's missing *if you view the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.java/)*, **it's pretty clear that `GestureOverlayView` is along way from providing this**:

1. Look at the `setGesutreColor(color)`, which you reference in your question. All this does is set a field `mCertainGestureColor` which is then used to set the colour for all draws.
2. Rather wisely, when you call `setGesture(Gesture gesture)` (that's every time you make a gesture) the developers of this class extract the path on line 286 of this particular version:

   final Path path = mCurrentGesture.toPath();

And then instead of storing every path that was ever extracted, they combine that new path ("`path`") with the master path currently existing ("`mPath`"), on line 292:

```
mPath.addPath(path, -bounds.left + (getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2.0f, -bounds.top + (getHeight() - bounds.height()) / 2.0f);
```

This means that when it comes to `draw(Canvas)`, we have no idea which paths came in which order.

3 . Which finally takes me to why 3 doesn't work- the information available to the draw method on line 394 is only enough to draw each path the same colour:

```
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mGesturePaint);
```

**So**, it should be pretty possible to just reimplement this class yourself to achieve your goals, but it is pretty much impossible to try and achieve what you want to with the current class.

Comment: Thank u for the response. I don't think writing my own version of GestureOverlayView is feasible for me. This is a very basic functionality. Existing class should have consisted that. Anyway, is it possible to achieve same functionality with something else like canvas n all?